# How can I create one list of dates with no overlaps from two lists of dates that may overlap?

Tags: c#, list, datetime

I have two lists of datetimes. The first list contains all possible date ranges that can be available. The second list contains all date ranges that are unavailable. I need to create a third list that is all the possible date ranges in the two lists and their status of available or unavailable. If there are any overlaps from the available list the date ranges should break up into multiple dateranges to make the available ranges not occur on the same day as unavailable dates. In real estate, you can't rent a house again if it's already unavailable so the dates that it is available is the date range of availability with any overlapping unavailable dates removing a part of the range from the availability.

Let's say the first list has available dates as:

```
startDate: 1/1/16 endDate: 2/15/16
startDate: 2/20/16 endDate: 12/15/16
startDate: 1/1/17 endDate: 12/15/17
startDate: 4/1/19 endDate: 10/15/19
```

And the second list has all unavailable dates as:

```
startDate: 2/16/16 endDate: 2/25/16
startDate: 12/1/16 endDate: 12/30/16
startDate: 4/1/17 endDate: 8/15/17
```

I want the result third list that I have to make to be:

```
startDate: 1/1/16 endDate: 2/15/16 Available
startDate: 2/16/16 endDate: 2/25/16 Unavailable
startDate: 2/26/16 endDate: 11/30/16 Available
startDate: 12/1/16 endDate: 12/30/16 Unavailable
startDate: 1/1/17 endDate: 3/31/17 Available
startDate: 4/1/17 endDate: 8/15/17 Unavailable
startDate: 8/16/17 endDate: 12/15/17 Available
startDate: 4/1/19 endDate: 10/15/19 Available
```

The second list dates should NOT change at all, while the first list ranges need to break around any overlapping dates. Note that the 2019 dates do not have any overlaps and are still in the list. I basically want to see all the possible dates something can happen while showing that certain periods are unavailable.

How can I do this in C# using List<>?

EDIT: It was asked that I show what I've been trying so far. As I mentioned in the comments, this is a simplified version of my actual issue and I don't want to spend all day "cleaning" my code for public use. Therefore I shall write pseudo code instead of actual c#. Assume I start with two lists, one being the available dates and one being the occupied dates.

```
    var currentDate = first date from available list
    var groupedavailableList = new list

    for i = 1 to count of available list
        If loopavailableDate[i].start_date <= currentDate.EndDate
            If loopavailableDate[i].end_date >= currentDate.EndDate
                currentDate.EndDate = loopavailableDate[i].end_date
       else
            groupedavailableList.Add(currentDate)

            currentDate = loopavailableDate

    //The loop ended, add the last current date
    groupedavailableList.Add(currentDate)

    //Now I have all the available dates grouped together in a bigger block of time (not tested yet). Now we do the part that is the question.

    var finalStatus = new list

    foreach date in groupedavailableList
        var overlapDates = occupiedList.Where(w => (w.StartDate >= date.StartDate && w.StartDate <= date.EndDate) && (w.StartDate <= date.StartDate && w.EndDate >= date.EndDate) &&
                            (w.StartDate <= date.StartDate && w.EndDate <= date.EndDate).ToList()

       If overlapDates.Any()
           //Don't know what to do at this point as there can be multiple over lap dates that break up the available dates.
           Foreach overlap OverlapDates
               If overlap.start_date > date.start_date
                   date.end_date = overl.start_date.AddDays(-1)
                   finalStatus.Add(date with available status)
                   finalStatus.Add(overlap with unavailable status)
                   //Now what? I now have broken the date of the outer loop by changing its end date. If I have two overlaps, I don't know the original period of time to determine if there is an overlap after.The first overlap works but the second in the same period of time doesn't.


        Else
            finalStatus.Add(date with Status available)
```

I would like the answer to be clean. I feel my code above is a little brute force...especially for checking for overlapping dates. I can't see it at the moment, but I feel there is a clever way to do this without so many checks.

Comment: What do you mean _"bend" around the second list_? Are you just wanting these to be ordered by `startDate`?

Comment: This sounds like a homework question, in which you haven't even attempted to solve the problem.

Comment: By bend I mean that the first list available dates will split up to wrap around unavailable dates. In the final list example, all the unavailable dates stayed the same, but the available ones wrapped around and changed. The end result would be ordered by start date.

@TheGeekYouNeed It may sound like it as I dumbed down my problem to have something to post without giving sensitive information away. The application I'm working on already has this working in VBScript and I'm translating to C# but I feel like it can be done better than what I see in front of me.

Comment: Change how? What is your logic? Are you wanting the 'Available' dates in the 3rd list to be the periods between the previous and next 'Unavailable' periods?

Comment: It looks like these just need to be inserted into a single list and ordered by start date? The dates you provided are sequential.

Comment: I see that you have sequential date order between available and unavailable records, you can use `var combinedList = firstlist.AddRange(secondList).OrderBy(x => x.startDate).ToList()` to combine them and order by `startDate`.

Comment: @StephenMuecke By changed I mean the date range would be broken up into smaller date ranges that are before and after the unavailable date range that overlaps. If there are no overlaps in unavailable dates then the available date period won't break up. The dates will not always be sequential.

Comment: @StephenMuecke I've edited the question to better explain it.

Comment: Show us what you've tried.

Comment: This is quite a simple task logically solve, and extremely easy to atleast attempt, why have you made to effot to solve this yourself first

Comment: @johnny5 I never said I haven't attempted it. I even answered that I already have a crappy solution in the comment above when someone thought it was a homework question. I don't see your answer below (since the question is so simple) so I don't understand the point in your comment. Neither you nor I have solved it and stack overflow should be a place where developers can ask for help without having to be "shamed".

Comment: @GuillaumeCR I've edited the question to show the pseudo code of what I've done so far.

Comment: @SolidSnake4444 I'm sure you have access to the review queues now, and you've been on the site long enough to understand what a well though out question is.  Despite all of that you original chose to ask a question that provided no work, or no minimal verifiable example.  So if you don't want to get "Shamed" for posting a question that will wastes peoples time, when you already had work done towards that would have been helpful to people attempting to answer.  Then you should consider following our guidelines on posting, and maybe you'd get your answer quicker

Comment: @SolidSnake4444 your almost there,  for all the dates that don't overlap. Now just break up the remaining overlaps into 3 groups, available dates fully overlapped that need to be delete, avaliable dates partially overlapped needing there startdate to be shifted, and avaliable dates paritally overlapped needing there end date to be shifted, and then shift the dates...

Comment: On a sidenote, if you put the effort into cleaning your code every time you check in, you can always be proud of it and show it publicly. Kinda like we all should keep our rooms clean ;)

Answer (score 0):

My approach was to create a single timeline with both available and unavailable timeranges, and then a small state machine to consume this timeline and spit out all the available time ranges.

The pitfall I ran into was assuming the first date was an available date.

```
public enum EventType
{
    AvailableBegin,
    AvailableEnd,
    UnavailableBegin,
    UnavailableEnd
}

public class Event
{
    public DateTime Date;
    public EventType Type;
}

public class TimeRange
{
    public DateTime Start;
    public DateTime End;
}

[TestMethod]
public void q41029109single()
{
    var availabilties = new List<TimeRange> {
        new TimeRange { Start = new DateTime(2016, 1, 1), End = new DateTime(2016, 2, 15) },
        new TimeRange { Start = new DateTime(2016, 2, 20), End = new DateTime(2016, 12, 15) }
    };
    var unavailabilities = new List<TimeRange> {
        new TimeRange { Start = new DateTime(2016, 2, 16), End = new DateTime(2016, 2, 25) }
    };

    var timeline = new List<Event>();
    foreach (var availability in availabilties)
    {
        timeline.Add(new Event { Date = availability.Start, Type = EventType.AvailableBegin });
        timeline.Add(new Event { Date = availability.End, Type = EventType.AvailableEnd });
    }
    foreach (var unavailability in unavailabilities)
    {
        timeline.Add(new Event { Date = unavailability.Start, Type = EventType.UnavailableBegin });
        timeline.Add(new Event { Date = unavailability.End, Type = EventType.UnavailableEnd });
    }

    var result = new List<TimeRange>();
    TimeRange currentAvailability = null;
    var insideUnavailable = false;
    var insideAvailable = false;
    foreach (var oneEvent in timeline.OrderBy(x => x.Date))
    {
        switch (oneEvent.Type)
        {
            case EventType.AvailableBegin:
                insideAvailable = true;
                if (insideUnavailable == false)
                {
                    currentAvailability = new TimeRange { Start = oneEvent.Date };
                }
                break;
            case EventType.AvailableEnd:
                insideAvailable = false;
                if (insideUnavailable == false && currentAvailability != null)
                {
                    currentAvailability.End = oneEvent.Date;
                    result.Add(currentAvailability);
                }
                break;
            case EventType.UnavailableBegin:
                insideUnavailable = true;
                if (insideAvailable && currentAvailability != null)
                {
                    currentAvailability.End = oneEvent.Date;
                    result.Add(currentAvailability);
                }
                break;
            case EventType.UnavailableEnd:
                insideUnavailable = false;
                if (insideAvailable)
                {
                    currentAvailability = new TimeRange { Start = oneEvent.Date.AddDays(1) };
                }
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }

    //result should be good here.
}
```

Note that this code makes the assumption that the list of available time range does not overlap with itself. Likewise, if the unavailable list overlaps with itself, it will break the state machine. It should be a trivial matter to sanitize the lists to make sure there is no internal overlap. Let me know if it isn't.